# Windows 10 Storage sense not deleting files from Recycle Bin

Tags: windows-10

I'm having a problem with Windows 10 Storage sense not deleting files older than 30 days from the Recycle Bin.

I have set Storage sense on in Settings > System > Storage. I have also set on the flag "Delete files that have been in the recycle bin for over 30 days". These settings have been on for over a month now. It's Sep 22nd today and there are still files from Aug 5th in the Recycle Bin.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem or how/when Storage sense runs this clean-up? I was really happy when I found the option, but now it doesn't seem to work.

I have Windows 10 Home build 15063

Comment: Just to be sure we’re comparing apples to apples: are you sure that the files were *deleted* on Aug 5th, or is that when they were last modified (or, perhaps, created)?

Comment: Yes, Deleted: Aug 5th, Created: Apr 19th would be one of the files. I checked by selecting the file, then clicked properties inside recycle bin.

Comment: Same issue here with 1809 build 17763.316. Recycle bin clearly shows files that were deleted more that 30 days ago. I'm seeing stuff in there that is almost 5 months old!

Comment: I opened an issue in the Feedback hub. https://aka.ms/AA4ga3v

Answer (score 0):

Storage sense only runs one of,

- Every day
- Every week
- Every month
- During low disk space
  whichever you have selected.

*When it runs* it will then delete anything in the Recycle Bin more than 30 days old. But if, for example, it is set to only run during low disk space, and you have plenty of free space, then it will never run. Alternatively if you have it set to run "Every month" then depending on the date of deletion, something could sit in the Recycle Bin up to ~2 months before it was deleted.

So far I haven't seen a downside to having it set on "every day".